# # of positive to # of negative instances

Tags: classification, neural-networks, dataset, conv-neural-network, anomaly-detection

I'm developing a spam detection classifier (the exact classification algorithm has not been chosen , I'll mostly go with CNN or NN). I'm fetching 20,000 tweets using *Tweet4J* and I'm a bit confused with the data collection. How many `+ve` tweets (spam) should I have vs `-ve` (non-spam)? I'm thinking to have 50% positive and 50% negative however, in real world spam tweets are way fewer than non-spam.

**Should  training data be of similar distribution to the real world data (testing)?**

Answer (score 0):

The task is to find the decision boundary in some high-dimensional space; first, it has to be as well specified by the data as possible, second, you have to approximate the boundary with your model.
For the first half, you're better off with a balanced sample than with an unbalanced one in my opinion.